# user input forget to key in the file name or accidentally press enter without break the program

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I don't want this script to be close or end if the user forget to insert the file extension or wrong file name or accidentally press enter without key in the file name. How can I do it?

```
def sum_usage():

    file_name = []
    print('\tMake sure the file is on the same directory with this script!')
    
    while True:
        file_name = input('\tEnter file name with file extension (.xlsx): ')
        if file_name == file_name:
            print('\n')
            print(file_name)
            df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0)
            print(tabulate(df, headers = ['Access SSID', 'Radio Frequencies', 'User Count', 'Total Traffic'], tablefmt = 'psql'))
            break
        else:
            print('There is no file name. Please enter correct file name.')
```

Something wrong here but I'm not sure:

```
file_name = input('\tEnter file name with file extension (.xlsx): ')
        if file_name == file_name:
            print('\n')
            print(file_name)
            df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0)
            print(tabulate(df, headers = ['Access SSID', 'Radio Frequencies', 'User Count', 'Total Traffic'], tablefmt = 'psql'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have found a solution to my own question.

```
    while True:
        file_name = input('\tEnter file name: ')
        if os.path.exists(file_name):  # I add this statement to check if the file exist or not.
            with open(file_name) as df:
                print('\n')
                print(file_name)
                df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0)
                print(tabulate(df, headers = ['Access SSID', 'Radio Frequencies', 'User Count', 'Total Traffic'], tablefmt = 'psql'))
                break
        else:
            print('\tMake sure you enter correct file name with the file extension')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the file_name is empty.

Example:

```
def sum_usage():
    file_name = []
    print('\tMake sure the file is on the same directory with this script!')
    
    while True:
        file_name = input('\tEnter file name with file extension (.xlsx): ')
        if file_name.strip() != '':
            print('\n')
            print(file_name)
            df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col = 0)
            print(tabulate(df, headers = ['Access SSID', 'Radio Frequencies', 'User Count', 'Total Traffic'], tablefmt = 'psql'))
            break
        else:
            print('There is no file name. Please enter correct file name.')
```